# How to make input field border red on alert dismis

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using `jquery conferm.js` alert for an input when presing a button If the input field is empty then showing alert that time it is taking default bootstrap 4(blue color) I want it to be red and should be focus in that field, so when user starts typing it should turn back to green I have tried but it is not working fine

```js
$("#save").on('click', function() {
  if ($('#numberInp').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enterThis field',
      buttons: {
        specialKey: {
          text: 'Ok',
          keys: ['enter'],
          action: function() {

          }
        },
      },
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#numberInp').focus();
        $('#numberInp').addClass('add');
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
})
$(document).on("keyup", "#numberInp", function(e) {
  $('#numberInp').removeClass("add");
});
```

```css
.add {
  border-color: #FF0000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
  <label for="numberInp">Number</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="numberInp" id="numberInp">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
  <i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;save
 </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to force it with the **!important** flag:

```
.add {
  border-color: #FF0000 !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

That works for me.

The reason is because in the CSS **form-control:focus** is defined first and it already has a **border-color** attribute. Since they are CASCADING style sheets (think top to bottom), if another control defines the CSS property first, it takes precedence unless you force it with **!important**

Answer (score 1):

@Zizzyzizzy is right, you might also need `box-shadow`:

```css
.add:focus {
  border-color: #FF0000 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 0, 129, 0.25) !important;
}
```

```js
$("#save").on('click', function() {
  if ($('#numberInp').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enterThis field',
      buttons: {
        specialKey: {
          text: 'Ok',
          keys: ['enter'],
          action: function() {

          }
        },
      },
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#numberInp').focus();
        $('#numberInp').addClass('add');
      }
    });
  }
})
$(document).on("keyup", "#numberInp", function(e) {
  $('#numberInp').removeClass("add");
});
```

```css
.add:focus {
  border-color: #FF0000 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 0, 129, 0.25) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
  <label for="numberInp">Number</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="numberInp" id="numberInp">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
  <i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;save
 </button>
```